# Left join and sum results

Tags: python, pandas

I work with Python and I try to implement the function `merge` with two tables df_agg and df_total. With this function, I used the argument `left` with the expectation that from the first table with the title all rows will be covered. For the first table, it is important to consider that the first table contains duplicates in the join column `id` while the second table does not have duplicates in `id.`

```
df_new = pd.merge(df_agg,df_total, on='id', how='left')
```

The merge command executes successfully.But the results are extraordinary, instead to have the same sum of `df_agg['total']` with `df_new['total']`, results in the `df_new['total']` being greater than df_agg.

So can anybody help me with what causes this problem and suggest to me some arguments in the function in order to have the same sum before and after merging?

Answer (score 1):

It means `id` has duplicates in both `DataFrames`, so new `DataFrame` has more rows like `df_agg` (is created 'product' of duplicated rows by all combinations).

```
df_agg = pd.DataFrame( {"id": [1,1,2,3,3], 'a':range(5) })
df_total = pd.DataFrame( {"id": [1,1,1,3,4], 'b':range(10,15) })

df_new = pd.merge(df_agg,df_total, on='id', how='left')
print (df_new)
   id  a     b
0   1  0  10.0
1   1  0  11.0
2   1  0  12.0
3   1  1  10.0
4   1  1  11.0
5   1  1  12.0
6   2  2   NaN
7   3  3  13.0
8   3  4  13.0

print (len(df_new), len(df_agg))
9 5
```

Possible solution is remove duplicates:

```
df_new = pd.merge(df_agg,df_total.drop_duplicates('id'), on='id', how='left')
print (df_new)
   id  a     b
0   1  0  10.0
1   1  1  10.0
2   2  2   NaN
3   3  3  13.0
4   3  4  13.0

print (len(df_new), len(df_agg))
5 5
```